# Negating the css property of one class with another

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
<div class="style1 neg">
    <input type="submit" value="blah" />
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.style1 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.style1 .neg {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

I'm trying to negate margin-top, but when I inspect the element in the browser, the 'neg' style seems to be ignored completely. How would I do this properly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The space, , is the *descendant selector*.  `.style1 .neg` selects a `.neg` that is a descendant of `.style`.  You want to use `.style1.neg`

Documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/dH7JJ/